Complex SQL update in the stored procedure
I'm beginner in stored procedures for Postgres. i have one working procedure and I need to change it a little:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION krv.delete_krvs_sridsv2(_krvs jsonb)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
BEGIN
  UPDATE krv.boxes AS b
  SET
      is_deleted = true
  FROM krv.boxes_data bd
  WHERE bd.rid IN (SELECT (value->>'rid')::text FROM jsonb_array_elements(_krvs) AS value)
    AND b.trbx = bd.trbx;
END
$function$
;

At first I will explain how it works - I need to update krv.boxes table base on _krvs. But here is the problem: krv.boxes doesn't contain trbx field. But table krv.boxes_data contains both fields: trbx and rid
The _krvs is data like
[{"rid":"rid1","info":"Some additional info...","dt":"2024-04-19 16:00:00"}]

What I need : the table krv.boxes contains field dt. I need to update this field also base on values from _krvs. Something like this:
  UPDATE krv.boxes AS b
  SET
      is_deleted = true
      dt = "Corresponding value from _krvs"

Please explain how to make it optimal.

please make a full [mre]  see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query also provide clear data not with ... on the middle.

Per UPDATE use WITH query to create a SELECT query that fetches the data from the join of the krv.boxes_data  and _krv tables. Then use that to supply the value to  krv.boxes.
